# How to find significance of Eta correlation?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, spss, continuous-data, association-measure

I am running a test of association between a categorical/multinomial variable (example: hair color) and a continuous/nominal variable (example: ratings of happiness 0-100). I believe the correct test for this is the eta (η) coefficient / eta (η) correlation coefficient / correlation ratio. I am using SPSS.

I have found many ways to calculate eta, but I am not finding how to calculate the associated p-value/significance.

So far, I have tried calculating via:

- Analyze > Compare Means > Means (Options > Anova table and eta)
- Analyze > Descriptive Statistics > Crosstabs (Statistics > eta)

I know that SPSS will run a correlation (Correlate > Bivariate) with these variables, but since the correlation coefficient listed is not the same as the eta, I don't think it is appropriate to use this p-value.